# Detecting Numbers With OpenCV Threshold or cvtColor in Real-Time

Tags: python, opencv, ocr, tesseract, python-tesseract

I am trying to detect numbers by converting the portion of the screen from its original colour to gray as well as applying a fixed-level thresholding. The idea is detecting the character's hp and mp values. Both results do not give a correct and an accurate result. I also upscaled the portion thinking that numbers could be read easily.

Original portion:

[image: Original image]

```
x, y, w, h = rectangles[0]
w = w - 155
h = h - 9
y = y + 5
x = x + 60

screenshot = window_capture.screenshot[y:y + h, x:x + w]
screenshot = cv2.cvtColor(screenshot, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

scale_percent = 250
width = int(w * scale_percent / 100)
height = int(h * scale_percent / 100)
dim = (width, height)
screenshot = cv2.resize(screenshot, dim, interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)

ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(screenshot, 150, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

config = r'--oem 3 --psm 13 -c tessedit_char_whitelist=0123456789/'
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(screenshot).replace('\n', ',')
cv2.imshow('threshold', screenshot)

print(text)
print('------')
```

When I change colour to gray only and print `text`, I get the following with `psm` 13 and/or 6. Other psm values did not show anything.

[image: Gray image]

When I apply threshold with `psm` 13 and/or 6 (other psm values did not show anything), I get the following.

[image: Thresh image]

What am I wrong that `tesseract` does not provide me values correctly? Is this approach the best way to detect hp and mp values?

---

Update:
I updated the code by converting the image from bgr to hsv, and the background is black with red text. The tesseract can now read fine, but it doesn't read the numbers when gray background behind numbers appear. After converting the image, the gray background turns into red. How can I have black background always or is there a better approach?

[image]

[image]

```
x, y, w, h = rectangles[0]
w = w - 140
h = h - 9
y = y + 5
x = x + 60

screenshot = window_capture.screenshot[y:y + h, x:x + w]
screenshot = cv2.cvtColor(screenshot, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

lower_white = np.array([0, 0, 0], dtype=np.uint8)
upper_white = np.array([0, 0, 255], dtype=np.uint8)

mask = cv2.inRange(screenshot, lower_white, upper_white)
res = cv2.bitwise_and(screenshot, screenshot, mask=mask)

config = r'--psm 11 --oem 3 -c tessedit_char_whitelist=0123456789/'
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(screenshot).replace('\n', ',')
cv2.imshow('display', screenshot)

print(text)
print('------')
```

Comment: I would suggest trying cv.inRange() on the white of the letters

Comment: Thanks @fmw42 for the comment. I got new results and updated my question. Could you please check it?

Comment: Threshold on white in BGR using cv2.inRange(). See if that works. Keep a narrow range for white (255,255,255) for upper and lower just enough to avoid detecting the gray background. Perhaps somewhere in the range of (150,150,150) to (200,200,200).

Answer (score 3):

I get better results with `--psm 11`. The code that was posted does not used the thresholded image `thresh` for the OCR. Finally, tesseract seems to prefer white text on a black background, so you could use `cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV` instead of `cv2.THRESH_BINARY`. The "INV" tells OpenCV to invert your image of white text on black background.

```
import pytesseract
import cv2
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = 'C:\\Program Files\\Tesseract-OCR\\tesseract.exe'

screenshot = cv2.imread('hpmp.png', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

scale_percent = 250
screenshot = cv2.resize(screenshot, (0,0), fx=2.5, fy=2.5)

ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(screenshot, 150, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)

config = r'--oem 3 --psm 11 -c tessedit_char_whitelist=0123456789/'
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(thresh, config=config).replace('\n', ',')

print(text)
print('------')
```

which gives

```
1263/1263,,/ 2101/2191,♀
------
```

Comment: Thank you! I updated my code by referencing your answer. Could you please check the updated section in the question?